# How do these two function definitions in OCaml differ?

Tags: function, coding-style, syntax, ocaml

I have seen some implementation as follows:

```
let rec fact =
  fun n ->
    if n <= 0 then 1 else n * fact (n - 1)
```

Another implementation is:

```
let rec fact n =
  if n <= 0 then 1 else n * fact (n - 1)
```

Could anyone tell me if there is any difference between these 2 styles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These definitions are equivalent.  The notation

```
let rec f a b c = <expr>
```

is a handy way of writing (syntactic sugar for):

```
let rec f = fun a b c -> <expr>
```

You can find this described in [section 6.7.1 of the OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html), under the heading **Local definitions**.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference apart syntactic sugar. The second form is defined to be equivalent to the first one.

The second form is usually preferred for stylistic reasons: you know at the line of the `let` that you are defining a function. In the first one, you have to read the `fun` to understand that.

Comment: (I don't use OCaml) What about the ability to apply matchers?

Comment: then you'll use the `function` or the `match` keyword.